# ubuntu 12.04 and higher can't connect to Lumia 800 wifi tethering

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, 13.04

this is my first post so don't hate please because I googled for hours about the anser to my question, but can not find.

I have a **Nokia Lumia 800 phone with Windows Phone 7.8 OS**

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS update on my notebook and I always connected to the internet with my phone. From that day, I can't. I updated to 13.04 but still not working.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the tethering?

Comment: @Jop via the wireless icon. It sees but always times out and can not connect. and an other info, that my phone indicates that i am connected

Comment: That's strange.

Comment: Yes, and it is a really big problem because I am leaving home tomorrow with my phone and my notebook

Comment: Can you connect to other Wi-Fi networks?

Comment: @Jop, Yes, I can